# How to use regex in babel include parameter in babel cli?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-cli

I want to transpile the contents of my `src` directory as well as some packages in node_modules with the help of babel . I'm using the following command as my npm script in package.json:

```
"build": "babel ./packages/myproject/src --include packages/myproject/node_modules/abc-,packages/leaf-sitemap/node_modules/qwe- --out-dir ./packages/myproject/dist"
```

in order to include all packages which start with `abc-` or `qwe-`

The output error I get is:

```
Successfully compiled 14 files with Babel.
/Users/me/code/packages/abc-schemas/src/index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import mongoose from 'mongoose'
```

Babel compiles the contents of my `src` folder successfully however it doesn't transpile the contents of node_module packages which start with `abc-` or `qwe-`.

What I tried:

1. using regex after the include statement.
2. adding include in babel.config.js at root level like so:

   include: [
       /node_modules/(abc-|qwe-)/
     ]

The babel packages I'm using: 
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5"

but all plugin proposals are of version 7.0.0.

Not sure if this is relevant but the packages which start with `abc-` or `qwe-` are symlinks. Not sure if this complicates my problem.

None of these attempts didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I tried a few more attempts with globbing as per `@Powell Ye` comment. I restricted myself to just `abc-` type packages. It seems that `-` is a special character in globbing patterns so removing it made progress:

```
"build": "babel ./packages/myproject/src --include packages/myproject/node_modules/abc* --out-dir ./packages/myproject/dist"
```

However I still got `Octal literal in strict mode` BABEL_PARSE_ERROR parsing error.

Comment: Have you tried using glob patterns? Which babel version is in question?

Comment: @PowellYe I tried `--include +(packages/myproject/node_modules/abc-*|packages/myproject/node_modules/qwe-*)` but this returned the error `sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('` I'm not sure if the globbing pattern is not correct or babel doesn't know to parse it

Comment: `--include`` doesn't seem to be a valid option in Babel CLI v7. Have you tried `--only`?